# decode route from google API

Tags: objective-c, routes, google-api, decode

i am desperately trying to find a way on how to get an Array of all the Coordinates (or a Polyline) from the google API so that I can draw my route on the MKMapView.
( By the way, I don´t want to use the RegexKitLite)

As I found elsewhere, this should be the right way to call for the API.

```
NSString* apiUrlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=%@&daddr=%@", saddr, daddr];
NSURL* apiUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:apiUrlStr];

 encodedString = ..... ????   // here i need some code before i can call the following Method


[self polylineWithEncodedString:encodedString];
```

and here is a method i found, to get a polyline.

```
+ (MKPolyline *)polylineWithEncodedString:(NSString *)encodedString {
const char *bytes = [encodedString UTF8String];
NSUInteger length = [encodedString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSUInteger idx = 0;

NSUInteger count = length / 4;
CLLocationCoordinate2D *coords = calloc(count, sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
NSUInteger coordIdx = 0;

float latitude = 0;
float longitude = 0;
while (idx < length) {
    char byte = 0;
    int res = 0;
    char shift = 0;

    do {
        byte = bytes[idx++] - 63;
        res |= (byte & 0x1F) << shift;
        shift += 5;
    } while (byte >= 0x20);

    float deltaLat = ((res & 1) ? ~(res >> 1) : (res >> 1));
    latitude += deltaLat;

    shift = 0;
    res = 0;

    do {
        byte = bytes[idx++] - 0x3F;
        res |= (byte & 0x1F) << shift;
        shift += 5;
    } while (byte >= 0x20);

    float deltaLon = ((res & 1) ? ~(res >> 1) : (res >> 1));
    longitude += deltaLon;

    float finalLat = latitude * 1E-5;
    float finalLon = longitude * 1E-5;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(finalLat, finalLon);
    coords[coordIdx++] = coord;

    if (coordIdx == count) {
        NSUInteger newCount = count + 10;
        coords = realloc(coords, newCount * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
        count = newCount;
    }
}

MKPolyline *polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coords count:coordIdx];
free(coords);

return polyline;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Code from here works perfectly well:
https://gist.github.com/Muximize/3770235

```
+ (MKPolyline *)polylineWithGMEncodedString:(NSString *)encodedString {

const char *bytes = [encodedString UTF8String];
NSUInteger length = [encodedString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSUInteger idx = 0;

NSUInteger count = length / 4;
CLLocationCoordinate2D *coords = calloc(count, sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
NSUInteger coordIdx = 0;

float latitude = 0;
float longitude = 0;
while (idx < length) {
    char byte = 0;
    int res = 0;
    char shift = 0;

    do {
        byte = bytes[idx++] - 63;
        res |= (byte & 0x1F) << shift;
        shift += 5;
    } while (byte >= 0x20);

    float deltaLat = ((res & 1) ? ~(res >> 1) : (res >> 1));
    latitude += deltaLat;

    shift = 0;
    res = 0;

    do {
        byte = bytes[idx++] - 0x3F;
        res |= (byte & 0x1F) << shift;
        shift += 5;
    } while (byte >= 0x20);

    float deltaLon = ((res & 1) ? ~(res >> 1) : (res >> 1));
    longitude += deltaLon;

    float finalLat = latitude * 1E-5;
    float finalLon = longitude * 1E-5;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(finalLat, finalLon);
    coords[coordIdx++] = coord;

    if (coordIdx == count) {
        NSUInteger newCount = count + 10;
        coords = realloc(coords, newCount * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
        count = newCount;
    }
}

MKPolyline *polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coords count:coordIdx];
free(coords);

return polyline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling...

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@,%@&destination=%f,%f&mode=driving&sensor=false",smAppDelegate.currPosition.latitude, smAppDelegate.currPosition.longitude, ((LocationItem*)selectedAnno).coordinate.latitude, ((LocationItem*)selectedAnno).coordinate.longitude]]];

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Response...

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
[self.responseDirectionData setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
[self.responseDirectionData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
[connection release];
self.responseDirectionData =nil;
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
NSLog(@"connection established");
[connection release];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *responseString=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseDirectionData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

NSDictionary *jsonObjects = [jsonParser objectWithString:responseString error:&error];
NSLog(@"responce = %@",jsonObjects);

NSMutableArray *ad = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"routes"];
NSMutableArray *data2 = [[ad objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"legs"];
NSMutableArray *data3 = [[data2 objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"steps"];
NSLog(@"Data3 %@", data3);

NSMutableArray *polyLinesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < [data3 count]; i++)
{
    NSString* encodedPoints = [[[data3 objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"polyline"] valueForKey:@"points"];
    MKPolyline *route = [self polylineWithEncodedString:encodedPoints];
    [polyLinesArray addObject:route];
}

[self.mapView addOverlays:polyLinesArray];
[polyLinesArray release];

}
```